# How can I use a function to populate data in a JavaScript object declaration?

Tags: javascript

I want to define an object, and use a function to populate an array as one of the members of the object. I have tried using a function both inside and outside the object definition, but neither seems to work. Is this possible? Here is a simplified version of what I am trying to do:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<p>object function test.</p>
<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
var test_object = {
    num1: 1,
    num2: 10,
    nums: make_array(this.num1, this.num2)       
};

function make_array(firstnum, lastnum) {
       myArray = [];
       for (i=firstnum; i <= lastnum; i++){
         myArray.push(i);
       }
    return myArray;
};
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = test_object.nums;
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

It seems that num1 and num2 are `undefined` when they are passed to the function. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a [`getter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get) here for the desired result,

```
var test_object = {
    num1: 1,
    num2: 10,
    get nums() {
      return make_array(this.num1, this.num2)       
    }
};
```

And let me tell why your code is not working as expected, the `this` inside of that object literal would point to the upper context, not the object itself.

This would be a better [read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work) for you.

Comment: Thanks. I tried this but got an error. I change the get line to: get nums () {.... and that worked.

Comment: @cmhodge Glad that worked for you. yeah that was a typo.'

Answer (score 0):

In this context, the `this` refers to the parent object (the `window`, if the code is running in a browser), not the `test_object` you're in the middle of defining:

```
var test_object = {
    num1: 1,
    num2: 10,
    nums: make_array(this.num1, this.num2)       
};
```

If you want the end result to be a plain object, the easiest solution is probably to separate the assignments so you can refer to the object by name:

```
var test_object = {
    num1: 1,
    num2: 10
}
test_object.nums = make_array(test_object.num1, test_object.num2);
```

(The ES6 `getter` referred to in another answer is also a possibility, though it works slightly differently (and doesn't work in some old browsers): the above would evaluate the array immediately; getters are evaluated when the value is requested. So with a getter, if for example you changed `test_object.num1` before reading `test_object.nums` you'd get a different answer.  This may or may not be what you want.)

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that `myArray` insider your function `make_array` is not declared.